# How to generate a single AR invoice for a week's delivery

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, invoices, oracle-ebs, logistics

Is it possible to create an Invoice for multiple Sales Orders for a period? I can see only the option to generate Invoice for every single Order.

As of now, every order is processed on receipt and an invoice is generated for each order. A new customer needs a single AR invoice weekly for all deliveries of that week, while daily orders are booked and shipped in order management.

Currently, we use EBS R12 and are printing the Invoice from the Crystal Reports.

Edit : Does Scheduling the Auto-Invoice program Weekly help on this.

Can someone acknowledge me, if this can be achieved. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share your table design?

Comment: Are you using an ERP ? If yes, which one ?

Comment: Typically I would call this a Statement instead of an invoice.  Combined Invoices are not unheard of, but they can get messy if your system isn't setup for it in way that manages the combining of individual invoice numbers under a single new invoice number.  Without this type of setup in your system, it can be difficult for AR to apply the payments properly once remitted.  However, a Statement would be a report of the various invoices produced for a customer over a period of time.  There are some customers who have policies that prevent them from paying from Statements though.

Comment: @R.McMillan Spot on ! Thats' indeed the clarification I need. If this is possible by altering the set up or the above flow, then any suggestions on how the setup can be would be of great help. Currently, we are about to start from the ground up. Thanks Mac !

Comment: Any suggestions from communities who already use this kind of invoice is much appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Yes @SudiptaMondal, we are using the Oracle EBS R12 as our ERP for AR processes.